# What does http://{s} mean?

Tags: javascript, json, http, https

In some json config files I see `http://{s}` appear. Googling this term just returns basic links about https. If I see the code below, is it using https or http?

```
"defaultPreferences": {
    "tileServer": {
        "title": "Basemaps dark",
        "preview": "http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/14/4687/6269.png",
        "url": "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        "crs": "EPSG:3857"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask the people you got the json from.

Comment: It's probably some sort of template expansion thing, but it's particular to some particular piece of software involved. It's not a generic notation.

Comment: And because the template notation does not affect the "http://" parts of the URLs, they're http and not https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is http, and {s} is just a placeholder, like {x}, {y}, {z}. they are  meant to be replaced with actual values later.